# How to use pass bundle parameter for paging in facebook android development

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, android-facebook

Actually i am accessing list of 25 pages which i have liked ( in my whole facebook accessing duration ) by

```
String graphPath = "me"
Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putString("fields", "music.fields(name,videos.fields(name))");  
mAsyncRunner.request(graphPath, bun, "GET", object, null);
```

from where i received data which i have displayed in my listView & there is also a JsonObject ( paging ) which is associated with :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100002420343415/music?fields=name,videos.fields%28name%29&access_token=CAAGjblaPDxoBAMH5FZBhdbJoJNALA0IiRGBgxLlWxlLixxTtxMUPVeo0AMkM1ZAFLZAOT7urdd1HeP1LQPJVsTSM9LDcnRUyABjSAxOHuljzRwkcbTHsPDloeA9CmZBMNPywubLPdz7PDrqaT3AC7MVxNHYLJh5tVhKI8tlAaZBoIWGGMhNKF&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=219447808080269
```

After receiving this , i want to access those pages which are present between `limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=219447808080269` for this i am using

```
Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putString("fields", "music.fields(name,videos.fields(name))");  
bun.putString("limit","25");
bun.putString("offset","25");
bun.putString("__after_id","219447808080269");
mAsyncRunner.request(graphPath, bun, "GET", object, null);
```

After performing this , i am getting the same data as `1st 25 Search` , i have also tried this ,

```
Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putString("fields", "music.fields(name,videos.fields(name)&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=206483212727507)");
```

but i found [here](http://questiontrack.com/implement-pagination-for-facebook-friendslist-using-facebook-sdk-3.0.1-android-1194742.html) that i have to change the path of `graphPath` so i have set this `graphpath` as `me/music`

thanks , tushar .

Answer (score 1):

This something will help :

```
Bundle bun = new Bundle();

bun.putString("fields", "music.fields(name,videos.fields(name)).limit(10)." +
        "access_token("+facebook.getAccessToken()+").offset(10).__after_id(265025693519613)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure of it but I was trying a similar query

```
me/music?__after_id=108196079208151
```

in the graph explorer and it was not working properly but if I execute this

```
me/music?offset=1
```

then it works perfectly. I think that offset and __after_id are conflicting in some way.

As a tip first check the results on [graph api explore](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).